# Append something to end of string using string substitution in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file abc.txt which contains text like that:

```
ABC01
ABC02
DEF09
EFG92
```

I want to append 'I' to end of every line in the file.
I am opening the file in vim editor and using the following command:

```
:%s/\n/I\n/g
```

But I am not getting the desired result.

When I used:

```
%s/$/I/g
```

I got what I wanted .

I am curious to know why the first method failed.

Comment: For silly reasons you need to use `I\r` in the replacement part.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Try this `sed  -ri 's/$/I/g' /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: I have tried it already and is working. I was curious to know why the first one was not working.